# Insert Excel file data in Word document using Python-Docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

I am working on some algorithm using `Python-Docx` Library to insert an excel file data in the word document. I will read that file from a location in my project and then will have to insert it as an Object to the word docx.

How do I achieve it? Is there any sample code snippet of doing this that I can make use of?

Comment: That's not possible using python-docx. I suggest you use a normal table instead. See also this [git issue](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/294) relating to this question.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. reference link for git issue was really helpful..Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is use pandas and python-docx libraries. Pandas to read the excel and then docx to write iteratively to docx file

```
import docx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")

doc = docx.Document()
t = doc.add_table(df.shape[0]+1, df.shape[1])
for j in range(df.shape[-1]):
   t.cell(0,j).text = df.columns[j]

# add the rest of the data frame
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df.shape[-1]):
       t.cell(i+1,j).text = str(df.values[i,j])

# save the doc
doc.save('./test.docx')
```